# Unable to build Facebook SDK for iOS on Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I cloned the latest version of the facebook-ios-sdk project:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

and attempted to build the project located at src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj, but it was unable to build because of the following errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoDIS.png

Is this a matter of Xcode 4 being a requirement for the latest SDK?

Comment: What gcc version are you using?

Comment: By default, Xcode 3 uses GCC 4.2, so I switched it to LLVM GCC 4.2, but it gave me the same number of errors.  I switched it to LLVM compiler 1.7, and now I get less warnings and errors, but I still get them: http://i.imgur.com/agEE1.png

Answer (score 0):

That feature (diagnostic push, pop) was introduced in GCC 4.6, the best to do is to remove the #pragma diagnostic stuff. You'll get the warning but apparently it is okay since the author choose to ignore it.